# How to call only 1 Test Step from TestSuite using for loop or how to add assertion only in 2 test suite out of 3 test suit

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have to add assertion in 2 test suit out of 3, written below groovy script for adding assertion in all step, but it is considering "Groovy Script" Test Step also, and hence script is getting failed

```
def testCases = context.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseList()

testCases.each

{

log.info "~~~Test Case:" + it.name

    for(testSteps in it.testStepList)
    {
        log.info "~~~Test Step:" + testSteps.name
        def Assertion5 = testSteps.getAssertionList()
        for( a in Assertion5)
        {
            testSteps.removeAssertion(a)
        }
        def Assertion6 = testSteps.addAssertion("Contains")
        Assertion6.setToken("REST Countries")
    }
}
```

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to set the assertion in all your steps except groovy steps ?

Comment: yes, I want to add assertion in all test step, but it is considering groovy script also as a test step, and trying to add assertion, which is not possible, hence my script is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, groovy scripts steps are considered as testSteps, but testStep contains information about its type that you can filter on. 
In your 'for' loop you should add a filter like :

```
if (testStep.config.type != "groovy")
```

and then do your processing.
That should work